# Loading image on ipad will not display using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

I have a web page that runs an ajax call that displays a loading image during the call.
This works fine on Firefox but does not display on an iPad.

I have tried a couple of methods to no avail including the blockUI plugin.

This is my html/css

```
<style type="text/css">

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

div.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.overlay.standard { background: #fff url(images/site/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%; }

</style>
<div id="holder" style="position:relative; height:90%; width:100%">
    <div id='map' style='width: 100%; height:100%; clear:both;'></div>
    <div id="loading" class="overlay standard hidden"></div>
    <div id="crosshair" class="overlay hidden"><img src="images/pins/crosshair.png" alt="crosshair"></div>
</div>
```

This is the script:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"search_build_json.php",
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        type:"POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{lat:cLat, lng:cLng, radius:radius}
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loading').show();
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#loading').hide();
        },
        success:function(data){
          //do stuff

    });
```

An example can be seen here
http://www.searchforsites.co.uk/json.htm

If you don't get any results based on where you live type Annecy into the box and click 'Find Location'.

Comment: so don't set async false

Answer (score 0):

```
try the following:
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#loading').hide().ajaxStart(function () {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function (e) {
        $(this).hide();
        });
   });
```